# Drawing Polygon C# OOP can't find Array

Tags: c#, oop, draw

I am trying to draw an Polygon in my WFA but it can't find the "curvePoints"in my class which are definetly there

```
class Driehoek : Figuur
{
    Pen blackPen = new Pen(Color.Black, 3);

    public void driehoek(Point p)
    {
        //this.x = 120;
        //this.y = 50;
        //this.width = 100;
        //this.height = 100;

        Point point1 = new Point(100, 150);
        Point point2 = new Point(150, 100);
        Point point3 = new Point(200, 150);
        Point[] curvePoints =
         {
             point1,
             point2,
             point3,

         };



    }

    public override void Teken(Graphics g)
    {

        g.DrawPolygon(blackPen, curvePoints); 
        // Error here is: The name 'curvePoints' does not exist in the current context
    }
}
```

Comment: obviously you need to move the __declaration__ of curvePoints out from the `driehoek` to the class level

Comment: The variable is scoped in the method. Declare it as a class member just like `blackPen`.

Comment: `curvePoints` is a local variable of your `driehoek` method. You can't access it in `Teken` method like this.

Comment: If I do that it can't find the point1,2,3 and as I need to use the constructor in my Form1.cs it must be in there

Answer (score 1):

Create a new `Point[]` in your class, right after you make the `Pen`:

```
class Driehoek
{
    Pen blackPen = new Pen(Color.Black, 3);
    Point[] curvePoints;
}
```

Then, modify your function *slightly* so that you assign an array to the existing array, instead of creating a new one:

```
public void driehoek(Point p)
{
    //this.x = 120;
    //this.y = 50;
    //this.width = 100;
    //this.height = 100;

    Point point1 = new Point(100, 150);
    Point point2 = new Point(150, 100);
    Point point3 = new Point(200, 150);

    //Changed Point[] curvePoints to just curvePoints
    curvePoints =
    {
        point1,
        point2,
        point3,

    };
}
```

Comment: It says point1,2,3 cant be used as a statement and it expects ; at the end of curvePoints

Answer (score 0):

> which are definetly there

It's a lie! Your array is in another method (out of "Teken" scope), not in class.

Comment: Yea but if I place them in there they can't find the point1,2,3

Comment: @J.Dekkers it is not a constant, you can declare it but assign later.

Comment: Still can't manage to get it work where to declare / assign then (pretty new to programming)